# Datatable search box is getting binded properly to first table and not second table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am facing this strange issue, my datatable search box is working fine for first table and not working for second table.
I am using this function for some reason, i belive it is because of this ?

```
 $(".dataTables_filter input")
          .unbind() // Unbind previous default bindings
          .bind("input", function (e) { // Bind our desired behavior

              if (this.value == "") {
                  table.search("").draw();
              } else {
                  table.search(this.value).draw();
              }
              return;
          });
```

Comment: This issue comes because of both the datatables have same name search field `$(".dataTables_filter input")` this will execute for both text box. You should try with unique id

Answer (score 0):

This is because, you are accessing the textbox using the class name. You should first check for the outer container div and then find the textbox inside that. Something like below.

```
<div id="containerDiv">
   ...
   Table Code Here
</div>

$("#containerDiv").find(.dataTables_filter input")
          .unbind() // Unbind previous default bindings
          .bind("input", function (e) { // Bind our desired behavior

              if (this.value == "") {
                  table.search("").draw();
              } else {
                  table.search(this.value).draw();
              }
              return;
          });
```